# Why does my discord bot play songs twice?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So  I want my discord bot to play music but when a song ends it plays it again. This also goes with the skip command. You have to use it twice. Here is the code for play next:

```
def playNext(self):
    if len(self.musicQueue) > 0:
      self.isPlaying = True

      mURL = self.musicQueue[0][0]['source']

      del self.musicQueue[0][0]

      self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(mURL, **self.FFEMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.playNext())
    else:
      self.isPlaying = False
```

and here is the code for skip

```
@commands.command(aliases=['skip'])
  async def s(self, ctx):
    if self.vc != "":
      self.vc.stop()
      await self.playMusic()
```

For skip it gives the error already playing music twice and stops on the second time and if you let it play both times it says VoiceChannel object not subscriptable. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your `musicQueue` attribute it's hard to tell, but it looks like it's a `list` of `list` of `dict`. So when you call `del self.musicQueue[0][0]` you're deleting the first element of the first nested list, but a list that only contains an empty list still has a length greater than `0`.

```py
In [1]: a = [[{"source": "abc"}],]
In [2]: len(a)
Out[2]: 1
In [3]: del a[0][0]
In [4]: len(a)
Out[4]: 1
In [5]: a
Out[5]: [[]]
```

You should consider using a [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) or a [`queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) that you remove items from using `pop` or `popleft` for the `deque` or `get` for the `Queue`. This will simplify your code.